# Reading Bytes From a Reader

Tags: rust

I'm writing something to process stdin in blocks of bytes, but can't seem to work out a simple way to do it (though I suspect there is one).

```
fn run() -> int {
    // Doesn't compile: types differ
    let mut buffer = [0, ..100];
    loop {
        let block = match stdio::stdin().read(buffer) {
            Ok(bytes_read) => buffer.slice_to(bytes_read),
            // This captures the Err from the end of the file,
            // but also actual errors while reading from stdin.
            Err(message) => return 0
        };
        process(block).unwrap();
    }
}

fn process(block: &[u8]) -> Result<(), IoError> {
  // do things
}
```

My questions:

- What's the "standard" way to do this? (I've been trying/hoping to use [and_then()](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.and_then)/[or_else()](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.or_else))
- How can I differentiate between the [`Err(IoError)` from end of the file](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Reader.html#error), and the `Err` that's actually an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The previously accepted answer was outdated (**Rust v1.0**). EOF is [no longer considered](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#tymethod.read) an error. You can do it like this:

```
use std::io::{self, Read};

fn main() {
    let mut buffer = [0; 100];
    while let Ok(bytes_read) = io::stdin().read(&mut buffer) {
        if bytes_read == 0 { break; }
        process(&buffer[..bytes_read]).unwrap();
    }
}

fn process(block: &[u8]) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    Ok(()) // do things
}
```

Note that this may not result in the expected behavior: `read` doesn't have to fill the buffer, but may return with any number of bytes read. In the case of `stdin` the `read` implementation returns every time a newline is detected (pressing enter in terminal).

Answer (score 3):

Rust API documentation states that:

> Note that end-of-file is considered an error, and can be inspected for
>   in the error's kind field.

The IoError struct looks like this:

```
pub struct IoError {
    pub kind: IoErrorKind,
    pub desc: &'static str,
    pub detail: Option<String>,
}
```

The list is all kinds is at http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/enum.IoErrorKind.html

You can match it like this:

```
match stdio::stdin().read(buffer) {
    Ok(_) => println!("ok"),
    Err(io::IoError{kind:io::EndOfFile, ..}) => println!("end of file"),
    _ => println!("error")
}
```

Comment: Another way to check for EOF would be `Err(ref e) if e.kind == io::EndOfFile` which is arguably cleaner (less nesting)